# Retrieving auto increment value:

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table 'prac1' with columns `id ( primary key, auto_increment)`, `Name` and `Contact`.  And another table 'prac2' with columns `id(foreign key)`, `Order_id(primary key)` and `Order_items`.

```
<?php 

$ok=isset($_POST['ok']);
if($ok)
{

    $name=$_POST['cname'];
    $order=$_POST['oi'];
    $contact=$_POST['contact'];

    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","learndb");
    $stmt=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO prac1 (Name,Contact) values (?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("si",$name,$contact);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO prac2 (Order_items) values(?) ");
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$order);
    $stmt->execute();


}

?>

<form action="prac.php" method="POST">
Name:<input type="text" name="cname"><br>
Contact:<input type="text" name="contact"><br>
Order Items:<input type="text" name="oi"><br>
<input type="submit" name="ok"><br>
```

Now, From this form submission, the name and order items get inserted to respective table with auto incrementing id in table prac1. How can i retrieve that id of table prac1 to insert into prac2.
And i guess because of NULL id in prac2 table the two tables are not joined and  the following code donot display anything.

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","learndb");
$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM prac1 INNER JOIN prac2 ON prac1.id=prac2.id ORDER BY prac2.Order_items");
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->get_result();

echo "<TABLE BORDER='1'>";
echo "<tr><thead><td>ID</td><td>Order ID</td><td>Order items</td><td>Name</td><td>Contact</td><td>Status</td></thead></tr>";
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['id'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['order_id'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['Order_items'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['Name'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['Contact'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['Status'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: [You could always try the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) as a last resort of course! _hint: mysql_insert_id_

Comment: I spelt that wrongly it shoudl have read `mysqli_insert_id()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<?php
    if( isset($_POST['ok']) ) {
        $name     = $_POST['cname'];
        $order    = $_POST['oi'];
        $contact  = $_POST['contact'];

        $db       = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","learndb");
        $stmt=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO prac1 (Name, Contact) values (?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("si",$name,$contact);
        $stmt->execute();

        //HERE YOU GET THE INSERT ID 
        $insertID = $db->insert_id; //THIS IS THE ID THAT YOU NEED ...

        // OR IF YOU ARE INTO PROCEDURAL STYLE: 
        // $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
        // YOU CAN DO THIS:
        // $insertID = mysqli_insert_id($conn)

        //THE REST OF YOUR CODE
        $stmt=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO prac2 (Order_items) values(?) ");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $insertID);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

Hope this helps a bit...

Comment: Well the least you could do if you are answering such _low hanging fruit questions_ is complete the second query for him

Comment: @RiggsFolly 
You are right except that he is still learning... and this is no low hanging fruit question for him... (For you as a Guru, Yes). He has also to learn to fill in the Blanks.... If he would depend on you doing everything 100% for him; He may end up a low-hanging fruit programmer instead...

Comment: @Poiz how can make sure that $insertID is an auto increment value of table 1 and not of table 2. And in the rest of the code you mention Order_items is not the $insertID. Anyway this helped.

Comment: @RiggsFolly
***So long as you ask for the insert_id immediately after performing an Insert Operation; you'd always get the ID of the very last row inserted into the table*** . However, if you perform another operation like insert again, You'd be getting a different result. In the above case, the $insertID is certainly what you want so long as the insert was successful ;-)